# OpenCl user event memory leak in CodeXL

Tags: events, memory-leaks, opencl

While normal events get destroyed properly when called with,

```
clReleaseEvent(ev)
```

a user event created with

```
clCreateUserEvent(context,err)
```

does not always get destroyed by release event.

The order of commands are like:

```
create queue
loop for 10 times
   create user event
   add it to 3 queues using marker
   add other things to queues
   signal user event so all queues start at the same time
   clFinish
   releaseUserEvent
end of loop
delete queue
```

Machine: amd gpu, opencl 1.2 64 bit implementation, win10 with a r7-240.

CodeXL says

```
0   545 9204    Warning Memory leak detected [Ref = -10, Handle = 0x000002792BC47070]: Object created by clCreateUserEvent
1   421 9204    Warning Memory leak detected [Ref = -18, Handle = 0x000002792BC477E0]: Object created by clCreateUserEvent
2   424 9204    Warning Memory leak detected [Ref = -11, Handle = 0x000002792BC478F0]: Object created by clCreateUserEvent
3   663 9204    Warning Memory leak detected [Ref = -9, Handle = 0x000002792BC47A00]: Object created by clCreateUserEvent
4   185 9204    Warning Memory leak detected [Ref = -22, Handle = 0x000002792BC47C20]: Object created by clCreateUserEvent
5   303 9204    Warning Memory leak detected [Ref = -10, Handle = 0x000002792BC47F50]: Object created by clCreateUserEvent
6   188 9204    Warning Memory leak detected [Ref = -20, Handle = 0x000002792BC48170]: Object created by clCreateUserEvent
7   427 9204    Warning Memory leak detected [Ref = -14, Handle = 0x000002792BC48280]: Object created by clCreateUserEvent
8   1020    9204    Warning Memory leak detected [Ref = -3, Handle = 0x000002792BC484A0]: Object created by clCreateUserEvent
9   548 9204    Warning Memory leak detected [Ref = -11, Handle = 0x000002792BC486C0]: Object created by clCreateUserEvent
```

Maybe driver is doing intentional leakages as a memory management?

Is CodeXL(version 1.9) or Amd's crimson whql(16.7.3) driver bugged or am I doing it wrong?

CL_SUCCESS are returned from both creation  and releases.

When I comment releases out, ref=1 for all leaks and their number is equal to loop counter. When releases are working, leak number is increasing with loop counter but not equal. Such as 45 for loop counter=100 but with even bigger negative reference counter values(example: Ref = -430).

Already tried adding "release" after all "clEnqueue" calls with temporary events amd this did not help. Also tried multiple "clRelease" consecutively and failed.

Note: user events are created, added to markers in queues, signaled and released in a multithreaded code block. Creation and release are in same thread, signaling and queueing in another thread. But wrapper does all operations in a memory lock block (C#) so they should see everything in other threads done. **When I ommit "marker" and "set status" parts, no leak happens.**

Program runs fine itself, computes stuff, synchronized accordingly with user events. I'm just curious if this memory leak is a bug of driver or mine.

There is an array of user events, releasing with

```
clReleaseEvent(evt[0])
```

isn't creating a copy of this event when passing as a parameter in C++ environment I suppose. clReleaseEvent accepting it as value, not referance. Similarly, there is also

```
clSetUserEventStatus(hEvt->evt[0], CL_COMPLETE);

and

clEnqueueMarkerWithWaitList(hCommandQueue->commandQueue.operator()(), 1, hEvt->evt, &ev);

hEvt->evt is not creating a copy?

even tried this:

hCommandQueue->commandQueue.enqueueMarkerWithWaitList(&(hEvt->evt2),&ev);

same result but hEvt->evt2 is a std::vector of cl::Event instead of an array of cl_event.
```

Comment: Quote from OpenCL spec 2.1, chapter 5.11:  "If there are enqueued commands with user events in the event_wait_list argument of clEnqueue*** commands, the user must ensure that the status of these user events being waited on are set using clSetUserEventStatus before any OpenCL APIs that release OpenCL objects except for event objects are called; otherwise the behavior is undefined." Later in the same chapter: " Developers should be careful when releasing their last reference count on events created by clCreateUserEvent that have not yet been set to status of CL_COMPLETE or an error."

Comment: I always release after I set them CL_COMPLETE and also after clFinish. Also I'm sure I release events first, others later.